# How to resolve npm dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

`react-tag-autocomplete@5.5.0 requires a peer of react@^15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.`

I am very new to React. I installed the following open source project:

```
npm install --save react-tag-autocomplete.
```

I was following the documentation stated here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tag-autocomplete

From the looks of it, I feel I have an older version of React. Am I correct?
How can I fix it?

Here is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "reacttaggautocomplete",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.0",
    "react-tag-autocomplete": "^5.5.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the project work with react@15 missing? It may be fine with react@16 and `react-tag-autocomplete`'s package.json just needs to bump their peer dependency version.

Answer (score 1):

Aparently you have installed React 16.2 so I'm guessing the problem is that  react-tag-autocomplete hasn't been updated to be used with the newer versions of react.

You could change the react dependency to `"react": "^15.0.0"` and then do a `npm update` and you should be fine (that will **downgrade** you to **react 15**).

Comment: This should be left as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Comment will be better.

Answer (score 0):

Install the package to solve it

```
npm install react@^15.0.0
```